Merge cells and add borders
I'm trying to format a table in Excel that has two levels of merged cells.
I'm looking to:

Merge cells that have the same value as the row below them in Column A, then put a border underneath it (thin, continuous, RBG code 153,153,153)
Repeat this operation for Column B, but have the border extend 5 columns to the right




Level 1
Level 2
Tastiness
Ripeness
Tartness
Sweetness
Priciness




Fruits
Apples
0.43
0.12
0.35
0.32
0.27


Fruits
Pears
0.17
0.33
0.32
0.68
0.61


Fruits
Pears
0.16
0.04
0.26
0.35
0.22


Fruits
Strawberries
0.26
0.74
0.40
0.07
0.37


Fruits
Strawberries
0.21
0.06
0.93
0.53
0.19


Fruits
Strawberries
0.21
0.18
0.38
0.07
0.04


Fruits
Strawberries
0.69
0.58
0.22
0.66
0.59


Fruits
Strawberries
0.60
0.14
0.01
0.99
0.68


Fruits
Strawberries
0.81
0.69
0.78
0.90
0.39


Vegetables
Broccoli
0.29
0.32
0.31
0.46
0.77


Vegetables
Broccoli
0.10
0.53
0.12
0.34
0.20


Vegetables
Broccoli
0.28
0.97
0.02
0.45
0.84


Vegetables
Broccoli
0.76
0.20
0.38
0.20
0.46


Vegetables
Cauliflower
0.78
0.29
0.45
0.73
0.77


Vegetables
Cauliflower
0.33
0.14
0.48
0.90
0.36


Vegetables
Cauliflower
0.12
0.50
0.75
0.72
0.63



Desired output, with the NULLs having a bottom border and merged with the first cell.



Level 1
Level 2
Tastiness
Ripeness
Tartness
Sweetness
Priciness




Fruits
Apples
0.43
0.12
0.35
0.32
0.27


NULL
Pears
0.17
0.33
0.32
0.68
0.61


NULL
NULL
0.16
0.04
0.26
0.35
0.22


NULL
Strawberries
0.26
0.74
0.40
0.07
0.37


NULL
NULL
0.21
0.06
0.93
0.53
0.19


NULL
NULL
0.21
0.18
0.38
0.07
0.04


NULL
NULL
0.69
0.58
0.22
0.66
0.59


NULL
NULL
0.60
0.14
0.01
0.99
0.68


NULL
NULL
0.81
0.69
0.78
0.90
0.39


Vegetables
Broccoli
0.29
0.32
0.31
0.46
0.77


NULL
NULL
0.10
0.53
0.12
0.34
0.20


NULL
NULL
0.28
0.97
0.02
0.45
0.84


NULL
NULL
0.76
0.20
0.38
0.20
0.46


NULL
Cauliflower
0.78
0.29
0.45
0.73
0.77


NULL
NULL
0.33
0.14
0.48
0.90
0.36


NULL
NULL
0.12
0.50
0.75
0.72
0.63



The VBA code.
Sub merge_same_borders()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Selection

    If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    ElseIf rng.Value <> rng.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(153, 153, 153)
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Using two Dict objects to collect the cells of Level1 and Level2
Interating Dict object to merge cells and set boarders

Microsoft documentation:

Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


Range.Resize property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim oDic1 As Object, oDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, ColCnt As Long, arrData
    Set oDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With rngData
        ColCnt = .Columns.Count - 2
        ' sort table
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Key2:=.Columns(2), Header:=xlYes
        ' load data into table
        arrData = .Value
    End With
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' for Level 1
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If oDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            Set oDic1(sKey) = Application.Union(oDic1(sKey), Cells(i, 1))
        Else
           Set oDic1(sKey) = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
        ' for Level 2
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If oDic2.exists(sKey) Then
            Set oDic2(sKey) = Application.Union(oDic2(sKey), Cells(i, 2))
        Else
           Set oDic2(sKey) = Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' Level 1: merge
    For Each sKey In oDic1.Keys
        oDic1(sKey).Merge
    Next
    ' Level 2: merge and boarder
    For Each sKey In oDic2.Keys
        SetBorder oDic2(sKey).Offset(, 1).Resize(, ColCnt), False
        oDic2(sKey).Merge
    Next
    ' boarder for column A & B
    SetBorder rngData.Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Columns("A:B"), True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub SetBorder(rng As Range, bInside As Boolean)
    With rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = RGB(153, 153, 153)
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    If Not bInside Then
        rng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        rng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
End Sub



